# Your system is out of application memory?

Tags: safari

I clean installed Sierra two weeks ago and now I have a new persistent problem:
"Your system is out of application memory" box shows up while I am using Safari and forces me to quit all of my apps except finder.
Out of application memory?
My activity logs show that this just isn't the case. 
I can see this being an issue all the way back to Mavericks when researching. 
Any solutions? 
Restart doesn't work.
Hard restart doesn't work.
Disk permissions repair doesn't work.
Deleted apps one at a time to see if they are the culprits (even though activity log shows this isn't the case). No dice.
I even brought my mac back to factory settings and clean installed Sierra.
Didn't work.

I'm being forced to close Safari (and subsequently every other open app like my VPN, iTunes, etc)about every 70-80 minutes.

mid-2010 i5 Imac, Sierra current version, iTunes current version

IPvanish current version

Comment: How much RAM does your system have?

Comment: 16gb. 4gb in each slot. All 16gb are active.

Comment: Aaaaaand now i have the black screen with curser on start up. Safe mode doesn't work. This just days after "out of application memory" debacle? Coincidence after only 11 days after clean installing Sierra? Hmmm...